# How to set background color via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, lit-element

I'm developing my web application using lit-element. I have a list of items each with it's own color. I render them as following:

```
render() {
  return html`
  <div class='container'>
    ${this.items.map(item => html`
    <div class='item'>
      item.data
    </div>`
  </div>`
}
```

Each item contains `data` - some info about item, and `color` - background color of this item.

I know few ways to set bg color per element:

1. `<div class='item' style='background-color: ${item.color}'>`
2. `<div class='item ${item.colorID}'>`
3. `<div class='item' onload=${this.setColor} data-color=${item.color}>` + function that sets color as `event.target.style.....`

None of this methods are as good  as I would like them to be:

1. Bad code decision.
2. Limits to the number of colors
3. Too much work just to set bg.

So, is there any good method to set the background color of elements like this?

Comment: What to you mean with "1. Bad code decision?" What's bad about 1?

Comment: That's what my teacher told me.

Comment: Bad teacher who didn't provide enough context. :-) I've also read somewhere some time ago, inline styles were bad. But if I **think myself**, I'd say in this case, it's perfectly fine. As soon as you'll have an actual problem with that solution, you can still change it.

Answer (score 1):

With pure js

```
document.querySelector('.container').style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

You shold write long css props with camel case

Comment: I've talked about it and it's bad. Point 3.